# How to get path to my npm repo from scripts when installed globally

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, npm-install

For my project, I have created a git on github containing some project related tools. The git contains a `package.json` and some binaries mapped to `bin` directives. 
While being a private repo and not published to any actual NPM repo server, it can be installed using

```
$ npm install -g git+ssh://git@github.com:<path to my tool git>
```

Most of the tools don't have any dependencies to other files in the module, and they work just fine. But one of the tools is a wrapper to start a [local DynamoDB server](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html), and my `package.json` contains a section like this:

```
"bin": {
    "ddb-local": "db/ddb_local.sh"
}
```

My `db/db_local.sh` file contains the java command to start DynamoDB:

```
#/bin/bash
java -Djava.library.path=DynamoDB/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDB/DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory
```

The `DynamoDB` folder is in the `db` folder which is in the root of my module:

```
<module root>
 |
 |- db
    |- DynamoDB
       |- DynamoDBLocal.jar
       |- DynamoDBLocal_lib
    |  ddb_local.sh
 |- package.json
```

After installation, `ddb-local` is linked from my node `bin` folder and can be invoked from anywhere, however the `ddb_local.sh` script will fail (unless the `<path to my module>/db` folder happens to be my current directory), since it tries to find files relative to the script, and the script will, in my case using NVM, be run from something like `~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/bin/`

Now, if this was a node script, I would be able to `require` files in my own module easily, but since it is a bash script I am not sure what the best way is to produce a valid path to files in my module directory.

I know that my package is installed under `~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/<my module>` and while I can create a relative path to my module's files using something like

```
`dirname "$0"`/../lib/node_modules/<module name>
```

this doesn't really seem to make sense. Surely there's an easy way to reference other scripts or files in your module from a script being globally installed as a binary? I have printed all environment variables etc, looking for something containing the path of my module, but with no luck.

Comment: Goto your module's root folder which is `my_module` in your case, and execute `npm link` and then go back to the location where you would like to refer/import and execute `npm link my_module`. Hope this helps!

Comment: While npm link might help, the purpose of this module is that other users in my organization should be able to `npm install -g` it and then be able to use the tools without having to resort to any extra magic.
The code I have now works, but it has a dependency to my module name and is also plain ugly. I tried using $0 and resolving the symlink that npm creates from $NODE/bin to ../lib/node_modules/<my-module> since that would at least give me the true path of my script, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a slightly better solution using a combination of `dirname` and `readlink`:

```
SCRIPT_PATH=$(dirname $(dirname $0)/$(readlink $0))
```

This uses the fact that globally installed npm modules are installed as a symlink from `$NODE_PATH/bin/<script>` to `../lib/node_modules/<npm-module>/<script>`.

It may not be 100% robust in all environments and it still feels like there should be an easier way, but it works.